# Export multiple files with InDesign Data Merge

Tags: automation, adobe-indesign, mailmerge

I am creating progress reports around 50 different companies in InDesign. The report is 10 pages long and has approximately 40 images and text fields that need to change based on the company.

I set up a data merge in InDesign and mapped all of the text and image fields. When I execute the data merge the text and images are mapping perfectly but it's creating one large 500 page report (10 pages x 50 companies). I.e. Report for Company A is on pages 1-10, report for Company B is on pages 11-20, and so on.

While I could break this up into individual reports in AcrobatPro, this step seems like it should be unnecessary. How can this be automated, preferably within InDesign? And how would I then be able to save each file based on a field in the merge csv?

Comment: I do not think merge can generate different files. You will need to write/find a script which will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nicolai, I don't think default data merge option can create split documents.
Maybe you can use the following script to split your documents into the parts
https://creativepro.com/free-script-splits-long-indesign-files/